# Is there a way to setup apigee to use external authentication server

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, apigee

Is there a way to setup apigee to use external authentication server, to better explain the situation:

- we generate a token from an app (test.app.com/services/oauth2/token)
- we send this token with the request to the apigee endpoint
- the apigee should call (test.app.com/services/oauth2/introspect) with authentication header (basic) and with body containing the token to verify it.

Im fairly new in apigee and have not seen similar implementations in my search

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you figured another approach to this but I would you a service callout policy to call the authentication server as below:

```
<ServiceCallout async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="SC-GetAuthPass">
<DisplayName>SC-GetAuthPass</DisplayName>
<Properties/>
<Request clearPayload="true" variable="ABCDLogin">
    <Set>
        <Headers>
            <Header name="Content-Type">application/x-www-form-urlencoded</Header>
        </Headers>
        <Verb>POST</Verb>
        <FormParams>
            <FormParam name="username">{server_username}</FormParam>
            <FormParam name="password">{server_password}</FormParam>
        </FormParams>
    </Set>
    <IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>false</IgnoreUnresolvedVariables>
</Request>
<Response>calloutResponseGetAuthPass</Response>
<HTTPTargetConnection>
    <Properties/>
    <URL>{authentication_server_url}</URL>
</HTTPTargetConnection>
```

Then I could just extract the token and pass it to Apigee

```
 <JSONPayload>
    <Variable name="authpass">
        <JSONPath>$.</JSONPath>
    </Variable>
 </JSONPayload>
 <Source clearPayload="false">calloutResponseGetAuthPass</Source>
```

Then you could just call the verification endpoint with the extracted token (I assume this would be another service callout)